# How to update (add or delete components) JAR File in .NET?

Tags: .net, jar

people,

I want to edit jar archives in a .NET application. That means, update classes and files inside. Is there any .NET way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A Jar file is essentially a zip archive, containing the java-compiled bytecode as object files, and other resources required by the application. So yes, you should be able to edit a jar archive by using a zip library in your .NET application. Depending on what you need to do, this might be more or less difficult (for instance, replacing a resource file might be quite easy).